# How to have the literal keys from an .env.example file typed?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to recognize as literal types the keys from all environment variables in an `.env.example` file, so typescript can call them and recognize changes in my application as I update the file. If I declare them directly, my application won't notice discrepancies between the file and the types. Also, I want to have a function calling only the environment variables set in that file.

If it was a `.json` file, I understand it could easily be done by importing it directly, as Typescript automatically types the JSON file's contents. Is it possible of doing something similar with the `.env.example` file?

Comment: Check the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package. As per the reload part, I think this will need to be dealt by your framework. For example, I'm currently using SvelteKit which kindly reboots the project whenever I change this or other files. If you want to implement the reboot mechanism yourself, I did something similar with the [watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fswatchfilename-options-listener) method from NodeJS.

Comment: What I really want is instead of `Record<string, string>`, to have the keys literally typed in the project. I accomplished that in the past reading JSON files in another project and it saved a lot of time and effort.

Maybe that kind of automatic typing is only doable with JSON files?

Comment: Ah! Gotcha. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to do so in an automatic way... I believe it works with JSON because it is no more than valid JS code that the TS compiler can interpret and infer data from but I don't know a way to make the TS compiler to correctly interpret `.env` files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is `keyof Type`

From [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html):

> The keyof operator takes an object type and produces a string or numeric literal union of its keys.

so something like this:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

// load the example file with fs.readFileSync or otherwise
const exampleDotEnvFile = 'contents of .env.example' ;
const result = dotenv.parse(exampleDotEnvFile);

export type Environment = typeof result;
export type Keys = keyof Environment;
```